# How to switch web camera while recording?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, camera, web-mediarecorder

Is there a way to switch web camera from `user` to `environment` and vice versa while recording using the `MediaRecorder` API?

Here is what have tried: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/imlegend19/pen/poNwbyw)